# I am getting random crash on my listview android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled

Tags: android

**My Declaration of attaching with header and footer sections of my listview**

```
 ListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.favoritesList);
 View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.favourites_list_header, null);
 View footer = View.inflate(this, R.layout.favourites_list_footer, null);
 favouritesListView.addHeaderView(header, null, false); 
 favouritesListView.addFooterView(footer, null, false); 
 favouritesListView.setHeaderDividersEnabled(false);
 favouritesListView.setFooterDividersEnabled(false);
 favouritesListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

**This is my getView method**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.favouritestext, null);

holder=new ViewHolder();

// my code goes here... 

}

}
```

**My Logcat**

```
10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:2991)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6846)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2257)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    10-30 15:06:39.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(337):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide some code , so users can help you.

Comment: can you help me out with some code and description ??

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1 this is the problem. I think it is sufficient for a question like this.

Comment: @Iavan glad that you have post the code.Why you don't update your post so one can get  better view of your problem?

Comment: I updated the post can you look after it send ur suggestion if any ..?

Comment: post some code of your ArrayList.java as logcat indicates that there something wrong at line no. 257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added header using this addHeaderView(View,object,Slectable);
This was the cause of crash, instead add header with   addHeaderView(View)

Comment: indeed. Be careful that onListItemClick is called when you click on the header view.

Comment: Not completely true. I have got header adding code same as you but still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Data being used by your adapter for creating individual row is going out of index.

For example if you are using an array of 5 items but while creating view of adapter you are trying to access 6th items of the array.

Hope this will help you out to pin point the issue otherwise post the code.

Answer (score 0):

step to reproduce

1 make a list

2 set adapter

3 add footer or header

4 make list empty

5 scroll and crash reproduce